# Inner spaces not detected on the client side

Tags: feature-request, bug, flags, character-limit

*Need of moderator intervention* flag requires at least 10 characters to enter for describing a problem. Before you do it <kbd>Flag</kbd> button is disabled. But if you enter something with inner spaces, e.g. `+    test!`, button will be enabled:

> [image: test-flag]

Pressing on the button closes flag window and shows me an error:

> [image: error]

Is it possible to use same check algorithm on client and server side here?

Answer (score 1):

Because Markdown is a marking language, continous spaces is treated as one **when rendered** (as is done in HTML) except for when it's in a `<pre>` tag.

The server checks if **rendered output** is long enough, but on the client side **the length of content** inside the TextArea is checked. That's the reason why the submit button is available but you can't submit.

You can, however, fill it with invalid characters to trick the server. See my comment below. If you want to know how, try to contact [*John Militer*](/users/321474) and he'll tell you.

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 tests carried.

## One happen when you type in the text box. It will count space too.

It is in JavaScript/ jQuery

## The second test happens in the server side.

If you check the network transaction, you can see it.

[image]

#### You got passed in the client side validation but got failed in the server side validation

## To reproduce, no need to fill it with spaces,

Just inspect it and remove the `disabled` property.

[image]

> Is it possible to use same check algorithm on client and server side here?

If a person want to bypass a client side algorithm, he can do it easily.